# What was the design rationale for making void not a primitive type?

Tags: c#, language-lawyer

When using reflection `Type.IsPrimitive` on a `void` type returns false.Coming from a C++ background this was surprising.

Looking at the [C# 6.0 spec](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/gh-pages/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.pdf#page=82) (Page 82) does not mention the `void` type, which could mean that it isn't categorized as a type altogether.

Is there anything in the language spec or otherwise that categorizes `void` as something else. Or any other discussion or such which mentions the reason behind this?

Comment: Just for clarity I'm not arguing if it was the "right" thing, just want to know the reason behind it.

Comment: `void` is just alias of `System.Void` structure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb.aspx

Comment: Have you read the spec? that would tell you exactly what it is.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev yes and so are `bool`, `double` etc, which are all mentioned as `Boolean type` or `Void type`

Comment: `bool` and `double` are primitive types, and the `System.Void` struct isn't. It's as simple as that. Note that all the primitive types can be manipulated using low-level processor instructions (although this is clearly an implementation detail) while `System.Void` cannot.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, OP knows that. The question is _why_. It _could_ have been implemented so that `typeof(void).IsPrimitive` returns `true` and the question now is: was there any special reason not to do so (like easily exlcude `void` from functionality supported by other primitives)? It's an academic question, and you maybe right that there is nothing interesting about it, but if there is, I'd like to know, too.

Comment: Change the question: why *would* `void` be any type at all? You can't declare variables of type void -- it's literally the absence of a type and only works as a keyword to indicate a method returns nothing. Do you also question why `unsafe` and `new` are not primitive types?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Your proposed question is wrong. `void` is a special type, but still it is a type. `typeof(void)` is legal. So the question is still, should it be a primitive type? And what is a primitive type? (there are multiple definitions, if I remember correctly)

Comment: @RenéVogt I though it was clear that my comment was suggesting why: `Note that all the primitive types can be manipulated using low-level processor instructions (although this is clearly an implementation detail) while System.Void cannot.` So I am suggesting that the "primitive" types are marked as that because they can be manipulated using underlying processor instructions - and this is likely related to marshalling and P/Invoke.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel indeed, the fact that `void` isn't a type at all was the point I missed and (at least for me) a sufficient answer to the question.

Comment: @RenéVogt According to the C# documentation, [`void` is an alias for the .NET Framework `System.Void` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yah0tteb.aspx), so technically it *is* a type in some situations.

Comment: Regarding the opinioned-based close-vote, I wish more people could recognize that the original design decision obviously was opinionated, but that the specific opinions that lead to that decision are hard verifiable facts.

Comment: C# doesn't even define the term "primitive type".  According to the C# specs `int` isn't a primitive type.  Nothing is a primitive type, because it's not a defined term.  Obviously if nothing is a primitive type in C# `void` obviously can't be.

Comment: @Servy From the [C# 6 language specification, 1. Introduction](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/gh-pages/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.pdf): "C# has a unified type system. All C# types, including **primitive types** such as **int** and double, inherit from a single root object type."

Comment: @PatrickHofman And does it define what the term is, and what types it refers to?

Comment: @Servy Good point, not very clear indeed. Later on it speaks about structs: "Just as these predefined types are structs, it is also possible to use structs and operator overloading to implement new "primitive" types in the C# language." So in fact that would mean that primitive types are value types + custom structs.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I strongly suspect that it's just a mistake, and that the author meant to use a different term (and a different term in each of those two contexts; I suspect the first usage was intended to say "built in" types, and the latter, "value types".  This is why the term "primitive type" should be avoided at all costs; different people use it to mean radically different things.

Comment: @Servy I agree. It is ambiguous at best and quite confusing.

Comment: I have been reminding Mads for *years* to take the word "primitive" out of there, and apparently it is not his highest priority spec issue. :)

Comment: The problem with "primitive" is not so much that it is ill-defined -- we could come up with a definition -- but rather, what is the use case? Frankly I would much rather have a type classification like "can have an unmanaged pointer to it". I just don't see the need for the `IsPrimitive` predicate.

Comment: [Steve Bourne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_R._Bourne) bought the *void* type into the C language as a stack trick.  In 1972 he pondered if *void* might be defined `typedef struct {}void;` (c.f. [AB33/Mar 1972 - paragraph 1.b.](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/algol/ACM_Algol_bulletin/1061601/p54-bourne.pdf) )

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Why isn't void a primitive type? Because it isn't something you can instantiate. It isn't a primitive type, nor a reference type. It is nothing at all.

Eric Lippert describes some 'problems' with the void type in [this post on Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/131099/113279), which goes into the specifics of `void` as a type to use in delegates and `Action`s:

> A type system is essentially a system for making logical deductions about what operations are valid on particular values; a void returning method doesn't return a value, so the question "what operations are valid on this thing?" don't make any sense at all. There's no "thing" for there to be an operation on, valid or invalid.

Making it a primitive type defeats the special meaning and purpose of `void` in the VES (Virtual Execution System), as Eric explains later on:

> The effect of a call to a void method is fundamentally different than the effect of a call to a non-void method; a non-void method always puts something on the stack, which might need to be popped off. A void method never puts something on the stack.

Making `void` a primitive type breaks this rule, although you could argue its usefulness, as Eric explains further in the post referenced.

Comment: I've always wondered about the usefulness of `Type.IsPrimitive` altogether - I've never found a case where it was useful at all.

Comment: I was creating a custom documentation generator which adds special  highlighting for primitive types and ran into this.

Comment: In short: it's not a primitive type because it's not a type.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It is a type, but it can't have a value assigned to it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Interesting. So, you are saying that `Action<T1, …, Tn>` is superfluous because I could just use `Func<T1, …, Tn, void>` instead? The last time I tried that it didn't work.

Comment: No. If you read the post referenced, you see how Eric explains that they didn't choose to support `void` as generic type parameter.

Comment: "A void method never puts something on the stack." Not even primitive variables local to the called method?

Comment: Eric designed it, so I think he is accurate. Maybe it is just what the method externally puts on the stack, not what happens inside? @JAB

Comment: @JAB, more accurate would be to say a void method never *leaves* something on the stack (when it returns).  Within its body it's free to manipulate the stack like any other method.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Eric didn't design the feature.  That feature was designed before he even joined the C# team.  He simply worked with people who designed it and had access to the notes from the old design sessions.  He was speaking second hand.

Comment: FWIW you can get an *instance* of `void` with `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(void))`, though it's a *terrible* hack obviously :P </nitpick>

Comment: @JörgWMittag From a more theoretical standpoint: Let's **assume** void is a type and you have `Function<T1, ..., Tn, void>`. If void is a type, we can't write a function for it, since there is no value that could be returned. The void *type* could be seen as the type theoretic dual to a false formula, if you follow the [Curry-Howard isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence#General_formulation). Some more "magic" based on the isomorphism can be found [here](https://milessabin.com/blog/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/).

Comment: @Marco: I wasn't suggesting that `void` should be a bottom type, I was suggesting that it should be a unit type, and a unit type definitely has a value (exactly *one*, hence the name "unit type"). In most languages that have it, the unit type is expressed as a 0-tuple, and the unit value as an empty tuple. E.g. in Haskell, both the unit type and the unit value are written `()`. In Scala, the unit type is `scala.Unit` and its value is `()`. Having a unit type and unit value is a great simplification in the language. I already mentioned that it would eliminate the artificial distinction between

Comment: … `Action` and `Func`. Even more importantly, it would get rid of the completely useless distinction between statements and expressions. Maybe it is because I have experienced both languages which distinguish between statements and expressions (Pascal, Python, ECMAScript, C♯, Java, among others) and ones that only have expressions, no statements (Scala, Ruby, Haskell, Smalltalk, Scheme), but I simply cannot understand why one would want to go through all that pain and complexity. Why do we need two conditionals, one as a statement (`if`) and one as an expression (`?:`)? Why do we need …

Comment: … expression statements and statement expressions?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I fully agree with you regarding these language design choices, I was simply suggesting that void, given its usual *naive* interpretation, is most likely a bottom type and in that case, your Function construction with void wouldn't work. Perhaps I got confused by the language game here; I am aware that void is not a type. That doesn't make bottom types or the correspondence to logic any less interesting, though, which was what drove my comment in the first place.

Comment: @Marco: I just stumbled across this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/234 *Suggestion: `void` as a first-class citizen*.

Answer (score 12):

`void` is not a type, it is a *keyword*.  Just like it is in C++, means the exact same thing.  Keywords play an exalted role in a language, they can only appear in certain places and the parser is allowed to make hard assumptions about the programmer's intention.

Primarily role is to generate good error messages.  Obvious on a statement like `return 42;` in a method declared void, you get a crystal-clear "hey, you said it won't return anything" error message.  Less obvious is that they are very useful to recover from basic syntax errors, a missing `}` closing brace for example is a pretty hard error to recover from.  When the parser encounters `void` while parsing a method body then it can reset the parser state and start generating good error messages again.

That the `System.Void` *type* exists at all is a quirk related to metadata.  The rough equivalent to a .h file in C++.  They exist primary to deal with technical restrictions in C++, it has no concept of modules, it uses a single-pass compilation model and demands that declarations always appear before definitions.  Pretty painful busywork in C++, albeit that editor tooling can help a bit.  No such restrictions in C#, the compiler generates the declaration from the definition.

Metadata describes a method in detail, stored in a MethodDef and MethodDefSig records in the metadata.  Two basic ways the CLR designers could have expressed the notion of "this method does not return data".  An obvious way is that they could have used a bit in the [MethodAttributes enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodattributes(v=vs.110).aspx), something like "HasNoReturnValue".  But since lots of methods do have a non-void return type, and space for it is reserved in the MethodDefSig record anyway, they just picked a *sentinel value* as the return type.  System.Void.

Reflecting on the System.Void type is not generally useful.  Realistically they could have picked any value for IsPrimitive and it wouldn't have made any difference.  False was a logical choice, it does not describe a type.

Comment: `int` is a keyword, too.

Comment: `for` and `while` are keywords too, they are not types either.  That the `void` keyword can appear in the same semantic position as a type identifier or keyword is a decision that predates C# by many, many years.  At least 1977 when C became typed, in turn inspired by Algol 68.

Comment: `bool` and `double` are keywords, too. The point is not that being a keyword, like `while`, makes it a type, the point is that being a keyword, like `void`, doesn't prevent it from being a type. `void` is a type. The reason `void` was introduced when C became typed is because `void` is a type.

Comment: It is a keyword in C and Algol as well, not a type.  It indicates the *absence* of a type.  Preferred over a blank space, for hopefully obvious reasons :)  Every programmer ought to write a compiler at least once in their career, then it starts to make sense.  Highly recommended btw, I never once regretted spending the time.

Comment: I find the assertion that `void` is not a type in C (or C++) strange. N1570 (C11 draft) 6.2.5/19 says "The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed". The C++ standard has similar wording in [\[basic.fundamental\]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#9).

Comment: It is both a keyword and a type just as `int`, `float`, `double`, and `char` are both keywords and types. It is the type on which no operations are valid. Saying it is not a type is like saying the empty string is not a string or the empty list is not a list or the empty set is not a set.

Comment: Sigh, no, `int` is a keyword, System.int32 is a type.  That distinction matters too, it is pretty doubtful that `int` is still an alias for Int32 a hundred years from now when everybody wears a 256 bit processor in their ear.  A lesson that the C language has thought us well.  Enough with the objections, please, just DV the post if you hate it.

Answer (score 8):

From reading the C# Specification, there is no mention of a *type* `void`. It is written about as a `return type`. In the table of contents, it is not categorised under reference or value types. It is mentioned as a keyword.

The section on the `typeof` function says:

> The third form of typeof-expression consists of a typeof keyword followed by a parenthesized void keyword. The result of an expression of this form is the System.Type object that represents the absence of a type. The type object returned by typeof(void) is distinct from the type object returned for any type. This special type object is useful in class libraries that allow reflection onto methods in the language, where those methods wish to have a way to represent the return type of any method, including void methods, with an instance of System.Type.

Which to me indicates that `void` has an associated type but is only used in the case where you want reflection to give you something tangible because of the type system. Otherwise `void` is just a keyword.

Comment: Are you suggesting a return type is not a type?

Comment: @DavidConrad no, I was stating that it's not mentioned in any reference or value type documentation, but is referred to as a return type, however, `void` by definition is a return type that specifies no type. So in a way, a return type doesn't have to be a type .... because of void